# Grant a role through Discord Bot in C#?

Tags: c#, bots, discord

I'm finding it impossible to use my bot to set the role/rank of the user to "PLEB".

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Discord;
using Discord.Commands;


namespace Spoxbot.Modules
{
public class Mod : ModuleBase<SocketCommandContext>
{
    [Command("geoff")]
    public async Task geoff([Remainder]string user)
    {
        var role = Context.Guild.Roles.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "PLEB");
        await (user as IGuildUser).AddRoleAsync(role);
    }

}
}
```

What I want to happen, is whenever a user types **!geoff**, it gives them the user of "PLEB"

This bot has admin privileges/powers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently your command is designed to give a user, which has to be included in the command a role.

```
!geoff insertuseridhere
```

as your question indicates, you want every user that types `!geoff` to receive the rank instead.

to achieve this you can use the context inside your command

```
[Command("geoff")]
public async Task geoff()
{
    var role = Context.Guild.Roles.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "PLEB");
    await (context.User as IGuildUser).AddRoleAsync(role);
}
```

**edit**
Based upon your comment, you seem to want it to work by mention.

For this you van make use of the IUser.

```
[Command("geoff")]
public async Task geoff(IUser user)
{
    var role = Context.Guild.Roles.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "PLEB");
    await (user as IGuildUser).AddRoleAsync(role);
}
```

Comment: I'd like it to be more like: !geoff @juan, so it assigns the roll to the person after the command.